# Получение значений массива

Tags: php, php7

Есть массив:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 42
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 49
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 21
        )

)
```

Как получить новый массив состоящий лишь из значений?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наверное все-таки надо вернуть значения по ключу `ID`

```
$result = array_map(function ($item) {
     return $item['ID'];
}, $array);
```

где `$array` Ваш массив

Comment: return $item['ID'];

Comment: Значения элементов массива в данном случае, тоже массивы

Comment: тогда вернется массив идентичный первоначальному

Comment: Ну да, возможно вопрос поставлен неправильно

Comment: на вход идет $item и возвращается $item. По моему автор имел в виду все же массив из ID

Comment: Спасибо получилось

Comment: @Дмитрий отметьте еще галочку под репутацией, что это является ответом на вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Существует множество методов, например:

```
$result = array_column($arr, 'ID');
print_r($result);
```

Или простой цикл сделать:

```
$result = [];

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $result[] = $value['ID'];
}

print_r($result);
```